# Sum all negative values of a df

Tags: python, pandas

I Need to sum up all negative values in a df...

I am trying to change this code to sum up negative values in a df. The desired outcome is to have a variable with the sum of all negative values in a df.

```
 df.values.sum()
```

illustrative df code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8), 'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for only numeric columns and then filter only negative values with `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[-4,5,0,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,-8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,-7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,-4],

})

df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
out = np.nansum(df1.where(df1 < 0).values)
print (out)
-23.0

arr = df.select_dtypes(np.number).values
out = arr[arr < 0].sum()
print (out)
-23
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly then:

You can use `numpy.sum()` and `ravel()` that's faster.

```
>>> df
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -2.054930  0.426327
1  bar    one -2.118650  0.007930
2  foo    two  0.164903 -0.567713
3  bar  three  0.310177 -0.568993
4  foo    two -0.683752 -0.127916
5  bar    two -0.816596 -0.299638
6  foo    one  0.038310 -1.323183
7  foo  three  0.146634  1.281159
```

You can also convert the boolean df to a 1-D array and call np.sum:

```
>>> np.sum((df < 0).values.ravel())
25
```